# Why doesn't this .vimrc mapping work in terminal (but it does in MacVim): map <S-Enter> O<Esc>

Tags: vim

I have two lines in my .vimrc file:

```
map <S-Enter> O<Esc>
map <CR> o<Esc>
```

The second line works as expected, but the first line does not.

The idea is that if I hit the Enter key then vim should insert a new line below the cursor position and move the cursor down to that line.  If I hit Shift-Enter, vim should insert a new line above the cursor position and move the cursor up to that line.  This mapping should work because the capital `O` key from normal mode will insert a newline above the line the cursor is on, place the cursor at the beginning of that line, and then place the user into insert mode.  Capital `O` followed by `<Esc>` should simply revert vim back to command mode.

I have checked and capital `O` works as I expect.  So why doesn't my mapping work?  I have tried using `map <Shift-CR>` and `map <Shift-Enter>`, and neither of those does the trick.

**EDIT** Turns out it works in MacVim but not in iTerm.  If anyone can explain why and suggest a workaround, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using Vim via a terminal? Some key combinations are not available on some terminals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using console Vim? Some key combinations can only be mapped in GVIM. In all / most Linux terminals, <kbd>Enter</kbd> cannot be combined with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Your mapping per se is correct, but you'd have to use a different *LHS* in the mapping.

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, some key combinations cannot be used even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll stick to MacVim as much as possible.

Comment: No, don't stick to MacVim. Use portable mappings instead: see `:help leader`, for example. Or better, use `oO`.

Comment: @romainl: I find `<Leader>` mappings fine for new functionality, but here the poster wants an overloaded meaning of `<Enter>`, and I agree with his chosen mapping, as it's close to the original. Something like `<Leader><Enter>` would be hard to remember (both for my brain and my fingers). This Vim limitation is really annoying.

Comment: I don't think it's generally a good idea to overload basic functionalities like that, specially using `map` which is probably too broad for what the OP wants to achieve.