# Can't remap <C-C> in vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, configuration, config, vi

I'm having issues remapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy visually selected text to the `+` register. At the moment I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
vnoremap <C-C> "+y
```

I tried remapping a few other things to similar key bindings to see if it was my implementation or the specific combination of keys that was the issue and it is definitely the key combination (eg `vnoremap <C-I> "+y` worked and `vnoremap <C-C> d` didn't).

Any ideas why it doesn't work and how I could possibly remap it?
Cheers

OS Ubuntu 16.04
Vim version 7.4
see [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/G9Uj4eia) for full output of `$ vim --version`

Comment: Take a look at this answer, I imagine it applies to this question as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073067/155299

Comment: From the linked answer mapping <C-c> or <C-C> should result in both <C-c> and <C-C> doing the same thing (which they dont..), probs gonna delete the question and move it to vi SE

Comment: Cross posted [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13709/1841)